# Correlation in matlab not working as expected

Tags: matlab, ocr, correlation

I am using matlab to implement a program that does OCR
I've build a template for each english letter + the numbers.

now I am trying to open an image and recognize the letters in it, for the basic start I've tried to load an image that is one of the letters template, the input image and the template image are the same in all parameters.
Now I passed the template array and compared each letter\number template to the input image (using corr2 function), I expected to get the right result because the images are the same, but other letter was found as better match.
what can be the problem?

*I am using the bwlabel to find the letter itself, and then cutting the image around it, and i'm working on binary images

thank you

Comment: If you'd add the code you used and maybe the images we can help you better. For instance, how do you threshold the image?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to do some preprocessing before calculating the correlation?
suggestions: convert to b&w, bump up the contrast, straighten the image, perhaps even resize to match size of templates

Comment: I know that I need to do it, but the images that i'm using now are the exactly the same, the input image is a copy of one of the letters template, which mean that they have the same size, same contrast and same angle

Comment: makes sense... =). what correlation value does corr2.m return for each template copy? assuming they are truly identical and you have not added any noise, the correlation value should be 1.00 for each letter. if it is, then there's probably something wrong with your logic. if not, then i dont think corr2.m works for you, in which case i would recommend you perhaps try to use the Hough transform (or other feature extraction transform) before continuing to match results.

Answer (score -1):

If your images are binary with the only values being zero and one, correlation probably isn't doing what you expect. That's because correlation involves multiplying, and anything multiplied by zero gives zero. To get correlation working how you expect, try changing all zeros to negative ones.